# Problems with binding scrollPane to Accordion (JavaFX 8)

Tags: java, components, bind, javafx-8

I have very simple programm and very bad bug-_-
In my programm I have ScrollPane, that contains Accordion. ScrollPane prefHeightProperty binded to Accordion heightProperty.

```
themeScroll.prefHeightProperty().bind(themeAccordion.heightProperty());
```

And when I collapse titledPane, the height of the Accordion decreases. And the height of the ScrollPane, too, must be decreased to a height of Accordion, but it does not decrease until the end.

[image: ScrollPane has green background]
(ScrollPane has green background)

Then I minimize the window and re-open it and see:

[image]

How can I avoid this problem?

**UPD 1:**

I know that I need call this code for resize scrollPane:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    themeScroll.requestLayout();
});
```

But where?
I tried to call it in `themeAccordion.expandedPaneProperty.addListener(...)`, but it isn't help

And if I will call it in `themeAccordion.heightProperty().addListener(...)`, then the problem is solved, but this code `themeScroll.requestLayout();` is called many times it's bad.

Comment: What is your purpose by binding the ScrollPane prefHeightProperty with the Accordion heightProperty?

Comment: @UlukBiy, I need to glue the button "Add new section" to the bottom of the Accordion. New TitledPane is added to the Accordion by the clicking on this button. Then when the window does not have enough space to display the new titledPane appears scrollBar in Accordion. For this purpose I bind prefHeight of ScrollPane to height of accordion and even bind maxHeight of ScrollPane to height of parentPane (in this case anchorPane). Therefore scrollPane stretched to bottom of window and then appears scrollBar.